# Undefined local variable or method `fritkot' for #<FritkotsController error message

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, mapbox

Please bear with me as I'm still trying to learn JS, Ajax, and RoR.

If you don't want to read through all the this nonsense, TL;DR: I have problems trying to incorporate geojson data from a regular ruby model into a map (mapbox.js), adding marker popups a long the way and using Js and AJAX.

I'm trying to include the mapbox.js (version 2.2.2) library into a Rails (4.2.4), but I keep getting this error msg:

> Undefined local variable or method `fritkot' for FritkotController

Here is the code in my controller:

```
# GET /fritkots
# GET /fritkots.json

 def index
   @fritkots = Fritkot.all
   @geojson = Array.new
   build_geojson(fritkot, @geojson) ## Where the error appears

   respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.json { render json: @geojson }
   end
 end

 # FIX: To be extracted into a class method (.self_geojson)?

 def build_geojson(fritkots, geojson)
   fritkots.each do |fritkot|
     geojson << GeojsonBuilder.build_fritkot(fritkot)
   end
 end
```

At the moment, I created a **GeojsonBuilder class**, but I'm thinking this should be perhaps a module or a helper extending or including my Fritkot model? Or is it the other way around? (I'm sorry if I'm mixing things up, it's just that I have worked on this problem the last couple of days and everything is getting tangled up).

Here is the code:

```
 class GeojsonBuilder

  def build_fritkot(fritkot, geojson)
    geojson << {
      type: "Feature",
      geometry: {
        type: "Point",
        coordinates: [fritkot.longitude, fritkot.latitude]
      },
      properties: {
        title: fritkot.title,
        address: fritkot.address,
        :"marker-color" => "#f86767",
        :"marker-size" => "medium",
        :"marker-symbol" => "circle", #fast_food
      }
    }
  end
end
```

Code on map.js

```
 $(document).on("ready", function() {
  L.mapbox.accessToken = "pk.eyJ1IjoiZHNvbGlzIiwiYSI6ImViNzgwOGZmZmVlMmVjYzg5ZjZhNzYxNDE3MWE0ZTFhIn0.0E-Z_FCmS8VHPRY07tVSEQ";
 var map = L.mapbox.map("map", "dsolis.ni76oel2", { zoomControl: false }.setView([50.854975, 4.3753899], 7);

  map.featureLayer.on("ready", function(e) {
  getEvents(map);
  });
});

function getevents(map) {
  var $loading_wheel = $("#spinning-wheel")
  $loading_wheel.show();
  $.ajax({
    dataType: 'text',
    url: '/events.json',
    success:function(events) {
    $loading_wheel.hide();
      var geojson = $.parseJSON(events);
      map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON({
        type: "FeatureCollection",
        features: geojson
      });
      addEventPopups(map);
     },
    error:function() {
      $loading_wheel.hide();
      alert("Opps something went wrong.");
    }
  });
}

function addEventPopups(map) {
  map.featureLayer.on("layeradd", function(e) {
    var marker = e.layer;
    var properties = marker.feature.properties;
    var popupContent = '<div class="marker-popup">' + '<h3>' + properties.title + '</h3>' +
                     '<h4>' + properties.address + '</h4>' + '</div>';
    marker.bindPopup(popupContent, {closeButton: false, minWidth: 300});
   });
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT 1:** Add Screenshot of error

[ScreenShot of where I get the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLOa5.png)

**EDIT 2:** Add Comment where the error msg appear

**EDIT 3:** Fix some code as per @snkashis suggestions.

**EDIT 4:** Here is [public gist](https://gist.github.com/dantesolis/29a6d23f3ceba4043746) with the code.

However, I'm still unable to load/view my objects on the map. I get this type of error when opening the console:

```
Uncaught Error: Invalid LatLng object: (NaN, NaN)o.LatLng @ leaflet-src.js:1122o.extend.coordsToLatLng @ leaflet-src.js:6206o.extend.geometryToLayer @ leaflet-src.js:6160L.FeatureGroup.extend._initialize @ feature_layer.js:94L.FeatureGroup.extend._initialize @ feature_layer.js:85L.FeatureGroup.extend.setGeoJSON @ feature_layer.js:37$.ajax.success @ map.self-9667db8b4bdc056a4ee3b0d7d005cf31e80d182ed0fc56a57b58ef94a30dd618.js?body=1:25jQuery.Callbacks.fire @ jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:3149jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith @ jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:3261done @ jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:9315jQuery.ajaxTransport.options.send.callback @ jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:9719
```

Here is updated code

**Controller:**

```
  # GET /fritkots
  # GET /fritkots.json
  def index
    @fritkots = Fritkot.all
    # @geojson = Array.new
    # build_geojson(fritkot, @geojson)

    @geojson = @fritkots.map do |fritkot|
      GeojsonBuilder.build_fritkot(fritkot)
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render json: @geojson }
    end
  end

  # FIX: To be extracted into a .self_geojson?
  def build_geojson(fritkots, geojson)
    fritkots.each do |fritkot|
      geojson << GeojsonBuilder.build_fritkot(fritkot)
    end
  end

  # GET /fritkots/1
  # GET /fritkots/1.json
  def show
    @fritkot = Fritkot.find(params[:id])
  end
```

**map.js:**

```
$(document).on("ready", function() {
  L.mapbox.accessToken = "pk.eyJ1IjoiZHNvbGlzIiwiYSI6ImViNzgwOGZmZmVlMmVjYzg5ZjZhNzYxNDE3MWE0ZTFhIn0.0E-Z_FCmS8VHPRY07tVSEQ";
  var map = L.mapbox.map("map", "dsolis.ni76oel2", { zoomControl: false }).setView([50.846026, 4.3491641], 13);

    map.featureLayer.on("ready", function(e) {
      getEvents(map);
    });
  });

  function getEvents(map) {
    var $loading_wheel = $("#spinning-wheel")
    $loading_wheel.show();
    $.ajax({
      dataType: 'text',
      url: '/fritkots.json',
      success:function(fritkots) {
        $loading_wheel.hide();
        var geojson = $.parseJSON(fritkots);
        map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON({
          type: "FeatureCollection",
          features: geojson
        });
        addEventPopups(map);
      },
      error:function() {
        $loading_wheel.hide();
        alert("Oops something went wrong.");
      }
    });
  }

  function addEventPopups(map) {
    map.featureLayer.on("layeradd", function(e){
      var marker = e.layer;
      var properties = marker.feature.properties;
      var popupContent = '<div class="marker-popup">' + '<h3>' + properties.title + '</h3>' +
                         '<h4>' + properties.address + '</h4>' + '</div>';
      marker.bindPopup(popupContent, {closeButton: false, minWidth: 300});
    });
  }
```

**GeojsonBuilder:**

```
class GeojsonBuilder

  def self.build_fritkot(fritkot)
    geojson = {
        type: "Feature",
        geometry: {
          type: "Point",
          coordinates: [fritkot.longitude, fritkot.latitude]
        },
        properties: {
          title: fritkot.title,
          address: fritkot.address,
          :"marker-color" => "#FFFFFF",
          :"marker-size" => "medium",
          :"marker-symbol" => "circle", #fast_food
        }
      }
    geojson
  end
end
```

I'm getting closer and closer to fix this up.

Comment: Can you tell us where you get the error?

Comment: @KevinDTimm just added a screenshot of the error.

Comment: imgur blocked at many worksites - mine included

Comment: @KevinDTImm,
Oh, ok sorry, didn't realize that. I get the error right in the controller at the "          build_geojson(fritkot, @geojson)" line. Added and EDIT for clarity.

Comment: I don't find any documentation on fritkot, fritkots or FritkotControllers - so it's very hard to understand what is happening here.

Comment: No. My apologies, I meant documentation on [geojson](http://geojson.org/). **fritkot** and **FritkotController** are the names of my model and controller respectively. Here is the link to the project in [github](https://github.com/dantesolis/fritmark). 

Thanks for all the help by the way @KevinDTimm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are still sending an [undefined `fritkot` to the `build_geojson`](https://github.com/dantesolis/fritmark/blob/master/app/controllers/fritkots_controller.rb#L10) controller method, [when it is expecting an array.](https://github.com/dantesolis/fritmark/blob/master/app/controllers/fritkots_controller.rb#L20) 
Secondly, I don't see the point of making an empty array in the previous line.
I'd suggest doing this in your `index` method for the time being, and then modifying GeojsonBuilder to only take one parameter and return one thing.

```
@geojson = @fritkots.map do |fritkot|
    GeojsonBuilder.build_fritkot(fritkot)
end
```

Change `def build_fritkot(fritkot, geojson)` to `def build_fritkot(fritkot)` and just make it return the Hash(meaning no `<<`) it makes instead of appending to a given array.

And to take a step further, [why run this expensive loop](https://github.com/dantesolis/fritmark/blob/master/app/models/geojson_builder.rb#L3) to generate the GeoJSON every single time someone hits your `index`...I'd recommend caching this somehow instead.

Comment: @thanks man, I got the map to load finally. But still unable to display my objects

Comment: Why are you trying to grab the JSON with $.ajax with an `dataType` of `'text'`, when you can just do `$.getJSON('/fritkots.json', function(geojson)`?Then you don't have to worry about parsing with `$.parseJSON`. If you still have an issue, please paste a gist of the contents of that /fritkots.json so we can inspect the payload.

Comment: Hey thanks @snkashis. Code is a combination of me trying to learn and someone else code. I'm still having problems. I'm currently working on the project, but I uploaded the pertaining files to a [public gist](https://gist.github.com/dantesolis/29a6d23f3ceba4043746) in the mean time.

Comment: Right now I'm just getting an ```map.self-9bdba3cb475f02d6f8f5758062991fd11b74cc98f433f22aee3dac332a22ac72.js:19 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )```, so I'm guessing I have semicolon or parenthesis where it doesn't belong.

Comment: `$.getJSON('/fritkots.json', function(geojson))` is your problem. Notice the extra `)` instead of `{`

Comment: thanks man. Thanks man. I finally got the map to display, however, and sorry that I keep pestering you, and everyone here, I'm still unable to see my data (markers) on the map. I just see the actual map. Nothing else. Any clues?

Comment: What errors are being thrown in your javascript console?

Comment: Right now I'm just getting the following error ```jquery.self-a714331225dda820228db323939889f149aec0127aeb06255646b616ba1ca419.js?body=1:9665 XHR finished loading: GET "http://localhost:3000/fritkots.json?success=undefined&error=undefined"```. Here is a public [gist](https://gist.github.com/dantesolis/29a6d23f3ceba4043746) with all the relevant and updated files.

Comment: Inside your `success` function of `$.getJSON`, you name the return parameter `fritkots` then don't use it....it should look like       `map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON({
          type: "FeatureCollection",
          features: fritkots
        });`

Comment: Secondly, I don't even see you defining `featureLayer`, just you referencing it as a property of `map`. You need to define it somewhere, probably in your success function. Get rid of `   map.featureLayer.on("ready", function(e) {
      getEvents(map);
    });`, just do `getEvents(map)` after you init your map in `var map = ..`then do `var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer({type: "FeatureCollection",features:fritkots}).addTo(map);map.featureLayer = featureLayer;`

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response, I got sidetrack fixing some other projects and trying to fix the errors by myself. Man, I'm going crazy here. I'm still unable to show the markers on the map. I don't know what else to do. AAARRRGGGHHH!! I get the following error: ```// ERROR 3 - Uncaught ReferenceError: fritkots is not defined map.self-274295e507a1b3b755a21370cbd50928cff58792175dd07e8e25695b873f38aa.js?body=1:29```. Here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dantesolis/29a6d23f3ceba4043746) with the current code and the modifications you recommended.

Comment: change  `var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer({
          type: "FeatureCollection",
          features: fritkots //['geojson']
        }).addTo(map);

        map.featureLayer = featureLayer;

        $loading_wheel.hide();
        map.featureLayer.setGeoJSON({
          type: "FeatureCollection",
          features: fritkots //['geojson']
        });` to `var featureLayer = L.mapbox.featureLayer({
          type: "FeatureCollection",
          features: geojson
        }).addTo(map);
        map.featureLayer = featureLayer;
        $loading_wheel.hide();`

Comment: thanks I would need to invite your for a coffee or something after all this. I updated the code, but getting the following error ```Invalid GeoJSON object.``` So, if I'm understanding this correctly, my single **(fritkot)** object is not being recognized as a valid geoJSON and this could be with how I'm constructing it the  ```GeojsonBuilder class``` or in my ```FritkotsController```. I think I might be duplicating my code or making it redundant at ```def build_geojson``` or ```@geojson```?

Comment: can you please grab `console.log(geojson)` in your `success` function and post that result into a gist

Comment: I get the same error, but here is a public [gist](https://gist.github.com/dantesolis/0ce3220906e63fd68caa) with the info.

Comment: That's a stack trace...I need to see the output of `/fritkots.json` endpoint..examine the request and see the response, maybe you can copy and paste that in.

Comment: here is a [gist](https://gist.github.com/dantesolis/e32b0eb5b1060adea035) witht the ```map.js```. Am I placing the ```console.log``` correctly? I'm sorry I really suck at javascript. I will continue working on this throughout the day so probably will update my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Go here to discuss with me - http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93501/fritkots-troubleshooting

Comment: ugh..I need you to send me the output of $YOUR_DOMAIN/fritkots.json. can you open that url in your browser and give us the results

Comment: chat here instead https://opentokrtc.com/fritkots - use text chat bubbles button in lower right hand corner

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the geojson at all, so I apologize if I'm way off but here's what I see programmatically.

You declare 2 variables: `fritkots` and `geojson`.  You then send `fritkot` and `@geojson` to `build_gejson()`.  `build_geojson()` receives `fritkots` and `geojson` and operates on a 'sequence' (array?, list?) of `fritkot`.

My 'guess' is that you should be sending `fritkots` to `build_geojson()` - if that's wrong, let me know and I'll delete the answer.

### [edit]

one other possibility, should you be sending `Fritkot` instead of `fritkot` to `build_gejson()`?

### [/edit]

Comment: I made the changes at you suggested.

Comment: The [geojson](http://geojson.org/) is basically an array of json for geographical coordinates. It takes the model's lat and and lng attrs and puts them in a coordinate array. At least that's what I understood from their documentation. So I'm guessing it should behave like any other json attr?
 
I made the changes at you suggested, but now I get the same error `Undefined local variable or method fritkots' for FritkotController`. I even tried to send them the instance variable **@fritkots** but then I just get an `undefined method build_fritkot for GeojsonBuilder:Class` error